# How to dispose in sequence text by using dropdown in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make in sequence title like this picture.
[image]

Whatever I selected, It will be dispose in sequence by using dropdown contents. 
I've tried like this:

```
public void DropdownT()
    {
        if (drop.value == 0)
        {

        }

        if (drop.value == 1)
        {
            tou.SetActive(true);
            t4.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (drop.value == 2)
        {
            sty.SetActive(true);
            t5.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (drop.value == 3)
        {
            acr.SetActive(true);
            t6.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (drop.value == 4)
        {
            ethy.SetActive(true);
            t7.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (drop.value == 5)
        {
            xyl.SetActive(true);
            t8.SetActive(true);
        }
```

Just invisible object before run, and select the dropdown it appears.
I have no idea how to solve it... Please give me a hand!!

Comment: Share what have you tired

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried.